# how to pass boolean arguments in spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to run (from Spyder) a python script that contains the following code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Project description')
    parser.add_argument(
        'nbr_workers', type=int, help='Number of workers e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--nbr_samples_in_total',
        type=int,
        default=1e4,
        help='Number of samples in total e.g. 100000000')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--processes',
        action="store_true",
        default=True,
        help='True if using Processes, absent (False) for Threads')
```

I know that I can use control + F6 in Spyder to submit command line options. However, I am not able to make it work.

Entering

[image]

generate the error

```
runfile('C:/Users/john/.spyder/temp.py', args='3 1000 1', wdir='C:/Users/john/.spyder')
usage: temp.py [-h] [--nbr_samples_in_total NBR_SAMPLES_IN_TOTAL]
               [--processes]
               nbr_workers
temp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 1000 1
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `nbr_workers 3 --nbr_samples_in_total 1000 --processes 1` in Command line options ?

Comment: does not work either....

Comment: `temp.py: error: argument nbr_workers: invalid int value: 'nbr_workers'
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i think i found the solution.

```
runfile('//***/.spyder/temp.py', args='3 --nbr_samples_in_total 100 --processes', wdir='//***/.spyder')
```

> OUT: Namespace(nbr_samples_in_total=100, nbr_workers=3, processes=True)

```
runfile('//***/.spyder/temp.py', args='3 --nbr_samples_in_total 100', wdir='//***/.spyder')
```

> OUT: Namespace(nbr_samples_in_total=100, nbr_workers=3, processes=False)

You have to ammend the process flag to `default=False` as you mentioned in your comment absent(false), that way if you do add the flag it'll be set to True